# Programmatically adding appointments to Windows Phone Calendar

Tags: calendar, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I was trying to look for a way to add appointments/tasks to the Windows Phone Calendar via the `Microsoft.Phone.UserData`. Does anyone know if this is even possible in the new Mango release?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get dates/appointments from app into windows phone calender?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473530/how-to-get-dates-appointments-from-app-into-windows-phone-calender)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. He's trying to add, not read.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh286421(v=vs.105).aspx) access to the Calendar is read-only

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible in Windows Phone 8.

**Edit** And yes, I know the question is tagged as 7.1. This is to let future users know.