# How to get dates/appointments from app into windows phone calender?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, calendar

I'm building an app that receives data about events (meetings etc.), and my task is to give the user the possibility for adding them (or some of them) to his device calendar.

Since there is no way in the windows phone API for write access to the user's calendar, how would you guys solve such a problem? Is there any recommended way to offer a file, data set or whatever to the user which he can store/add easily?

Comment: You could perhaps email the user the agenda item in a outlook invite style and let them add it like that. Or open a webbrowser that automatically access a website that generates such an item.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a web service that outputs iCalendar (.ics) files and open them on your phone in a collapsed WebBrowser - that could work.